# Perl, to find the common lines between text files in a Dir

Tags: perl

I have found the code for read all the text file in a directory. But I don't know how to find the commonality between them. Please help me with the code, or share on what area I need to explore more. There is too much to learn but I have a time constraint.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English;

my $dir = 'C:\Perl_Example\Data';

foreach my $fp (glob("$dir/*.txt")) 
{
  printf "%s\n", $fp;
  #the file header
  
  open my $fh, "<", $fp or die "can't read open '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
  #open file to read which is each file in dir
  
  
  while (<$fh>) 
  {
    printf "  %s", $_;
    #print the file content
  }
  
  close $fh or die "can't read close '$fp': $OS_ERROR";
}
```

Comment: [Algorithm::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff)?

Comment: What kind of "commonality" are you looking for?  A certain name?   A particular pattern that appears in multiple files?  Phone numbers?  ...?  Once you have a line in your hand, inside that `while` loop, then process it to find/build that which should be "common" to files.  So, what is it?

Comment: @zdim it is actually dir for data log. I want to find the common error between the hundreds of text file

Comment: "_want to find the common error_" -- alright, so what is common between them?  Let me guess ... they all have a word "ERROR" in them?  See, can't guess :)   There should be some pattern, word, something.  Or you mean *anything* that's common?  Could build a word-frequency structure but that's too broad and it would miss phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to "find the common lines".  Of course, there is more than one way to do that in Perl :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my %h;

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    open (my $fh, $file) or die "$file: $!\n";
    while(<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        push @{$h{$_}}, $file;
    }
}

for (sort keys %h) {
    if(@{$h{$_}} > 1) {
        print "line <$_>\n";
        print "  occurs in ", join(", ", @{$h{$_}}), "\n";
    }
}

exit 0;
```

Now the test files, named {1,2,3}:

```
% cat 1
PING YA.RU (87.250.250.242): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=0 ttl=249 time=14.615 ms
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=1 ttl=249 time=14.943 ms
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=2 ttl=249 time=14.381 ms
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=3 ttl=249 time=14.852 ms
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=4 ttl=249 time=14.791 ms
% cat 2
PING YA.RU (87.250.250.242): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=0 ttl=249 time=14.615 ms
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=3 ttl=249 time=14.852 ms
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=4 ttl=249 time=14.791 ms
% cat 3
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=3 ttl=249 time=14.852 ms
64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=4 ttl=249 time=14.791 ms
```

And test run of the script:

```
% ./try.pl 1 2 3
line <64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=0 ttl=249 time=14.615 ms>
  occurs in 1, 2
line <64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=3 ttl=249 time=14.852 ms>
  occurs in 1, 2, 3
line <64 bytes from 87.250.250.242: icmp_seq=4 ttl=249 time=14.791 ms>
  occurs in 1, 2, 3
line <PING YA.RU (87.250.250.242): 56 data bytes>
  occurs in 1, 2
```